# Scale image to the center of the screen from the gallery using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

There is a cubic gallery of images and my requirement is that on mouse hover any image should scale in the middle of the screen. I went through some solutions but they scale image at the exact location it is currently present on the screen.

While the image is scaled all the remaining gallery should go in background.

Please suggest me an approach for doing this And please let me know in case of any code to be posted.

Comment: Any reason for a negative vote ?

Comment: I would suggest updating the image to use absolute position and using something like left: 50% and top:50%. This is just a rough idea with the css though. You will need to adjust based on your actual code.

Comment: @NendoTaka Yes this seems to be a good suggestion and that I can update the z index at the same time on hover so it will act as a top layer. Let me try this out

Comment: `please let me know in case of any code to be posted` - so you have some code? does it "almost" work? did you need help with it?

Comment: @jaromanda X yes almost could do the thing it worked too Thank you Please see in the answer and suggest any improvement in the css

Comment: I'm seeing into the future because there is no answer now

Comment: @JaromandaX added now did you do negative vote ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suggested by Joramanda on adding above suggestion this seems to be working fine. Below is the css so the left right top and z index were adjusted to generate the desired effect.

```
.polaroid {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    float: left;
    border: thin;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1);
}

img {
    width: 100%
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1);

}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.polaroid:HOVER {
    position:absolute;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    top:20%;
    z-index:10;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.9);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.5);

}
```